# Doxygen - using doxygen with gswin64c.exe

Tags: doxygen

Where do I configure doxygen to use the 64-bit verions of ghostscript?  It seems by default doxygen calls for gswin32c.exe rather than gswin64c.exe.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Lazy solution: copied gswin32c.exe to gswin64c.exe. Sorry, I'm in a rush and couldn't find the proper solution and didn't want to install 32-bit ghostscript.

Comment: This worked for me, although it'd be nice to have a prettier solution!